# What is the hottest part, under light load?

Tags: sensor, temperature, cpu

For a hobbyist **weather station** project I am going to use a Raspberry Pi and a Si7021 temperature/humidity sensor. If possible, I want to use one of the available casings, and enclose my Pi and the sensor in the casing. Now I wonder how to minimize the measurement error.

So, where to place my my sensor best? **What is the hottest part on a Raspberry Pi under light load?** I guess the CPU, but maybe it could also be the USB for the power input?

These constraints apply:

- headless mode, no monitor or USB use
- LAN access
- [Casing is this, which has some holes in it](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00UJZ7VDK) Image: [image: Casing to use]
- I intend the case to wall-mount
- Model is a Raspberry Pi 2, Model B
- As an indicator, the core temperature is typically around 42 to 44 degrees Celsius.

Note:

- A FLIR camera would help of course, but I do not have access to one of those.

Comment: It does seem a bit pointless to have one within the case.  You will just be measuring the temperature and humidity of your micro-climate.  It will be unrelated to the outside environment.

Answer (score 2):

I used to measure **temperature on the Raspberry** under **different load**.

I remember if you used something on the USB port, or the ethernet, the **chip driving USB and ethernet** becomes **hotter than the CPU**.

(I have a 3B+) But this should be true on the 2B. Anyways, the differences will be very very tiny.

Try find an **infrared thermometer** if you want to be sure they are not very expensive and can do a lot in DIY project !

---

---

**As said by@Joan :**

If you put your sensors in the same case/box that the raspberry you bill be monitoring the raspberry ! You need to put theses sensor outside of the box in order to monitor weather. Your electronic protected in your external case, and the sensor out of it.